# C4800 warning, how to find where in the source code

Tags: visual-c++, stl

Is there a smart way to find the relevant places in the code when you get warnings like this? It seems the only line number shown refers to standard headers but not the actual code. I must add that the project is very large with hundreds of modules and 1MLOC+.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\utility(138): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtree(1804) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>,int>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>>,
              _Ty2=bool,
              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>,
              _Other1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>>,
              _Other2=int
          ]
          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xtree(1804) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>,int>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&,void **)' being compiled
          with
          [
              _Ty1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>>,
              _Ty2=bool,
              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>,
              _Other1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,tpuTask >>>>,
              _Other2=int
          ]
...
```

Comment: You'd better take a good look at your "tpuTask" class.  It appears to permit a conversion to bool.  That's almost always unintended, the reason this warning is displayed.  Pointer conversions are the usual issue, a big reason that nullptr was added to C++11.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right, the system (ab)uses a way to convert a generic union pointer to various data types and I think this doesn't work well in some C++ specific cases like when the type instance in a STL container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has no problems.

But unfortunately, the code in VC standard headers is not warning-free in level 4. You can only disable that warning using the compiler option.